# "Yoga philosophy" or "Yoga's philosophy": Difference in meaning with or without the possessive apostrophe?

Tags: meaning, possessives, apostrophe

For me it feels like there's a difference in meaning but I'm unable to pin it down. It's clear that "Yoga's philosophy" would indicate possession while "Yoga philosophy" wouldn't but I'm unsure of the consequences.

Context: Currently analytically coding some interviews concerning Yoga.

Comment: Yogi's philosophy, meanwhile, is "If you come to a fork in the road, take it."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two are essentially similar, but there is a subtle difference.

In the former, Yoga is acting as an adjective to clarify what sort of philosophy is being talked about.  It is the philosophy *associated with* Yoga.

In the second, it's a possessive.  It's the philosophy *belonging to* Yoga.